# Laravel : How to orderBy on a One to One inverse relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-request

I have a `Asset` model and `AssetCategory` model. The `asset` model has function

```
$this->belongsTo('App\AssetCategory' ); //inverse one to one
```

My `assets` table has columns `id` , `name` , `assetcategory_id` .

Now, when I want to populate my assets list and sort it according to asset name, I can simply write

`$assets = Asset::orderBy('name' , 'asc')->get();`

But how do I sort according to the asset categories that are populated in my output. I am using laravel 5.3

Comment: what are the columns are there in asset categories ? and which one you want to use for sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

Join would be simple and will solve your problem.

```
Asset::select(
'assets.id as asset_id',
'assets.name as asset_name',
'assets.assetcategory_id',
'assetcategories.name as assetcategory_name')
->leftJoin('assetcategories','assetcategories.id','=','assets.assetcategory_id')
->groupBy('asset_id')
->orderBy('assetcategory_name','asc')
->get();
```

Note: I'm assuming you've used proper naming convention of laravel. Let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry your query didnt work. However, I was able to solve the issue using 
Asset::join('assetcategories', 'assets.assetcategory_id', '=', 'assetcategories.id')->orderby('assetcategories.name','asc')->with('assetcategory')->get(); 

I also tried eager loading the assetcategories table first. But that produced the same result as before.

Comment: well it could have very small glitch because I couldn't try it anywhere. and nice to hear you made it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that you have a function like this in  your model

```
public function assetCategory()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\AssetCategory');
}
```

now in your controller you can fetch asset name

```
$assets = Asset::orderBy('name' , 'asc')->get();
```

this way you can fetch asset category

```
$assets->assetCategory()->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
Asset::join('asset_categories', 'assets.asset_category_id', '=', 'asset_categories.id')
    ->orderBy('asset_categories.name', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('assets.id')
    ->select('assets.*')
    ->get();
```

Taking `assets` and `asset_categories` as table names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry your query didnt work. However, I was able to solve the issue using Asset::join('assetcategories', 'assets.assetcategory_id', '=', 'assetcategories.id')->orderby('assetcategories.name','asc')‌​->with('assetcategor‌​y')->get(); I also tried eager loading the assetcategories table first. But that produced the same result as before.